Can http server send a data to client without client's request?
I write simple http(https)-client in C++.
How the client should handle a data from a server if the client received it without it's request ?
Or before client has sent it's request ?
Should the client simply disconnect or ignore received data?
PS: I am not considering websocket-connection.

There are not many technical possibilities for a server to send data to a client in the absence of a request. There are 2 things that come to my mind: web sockets or server sent events

"I write simple http(https)-client in C++." As in: you are implementing entire HTTP protocol from scratch? Don't. Seriously, just don't. "Or before client has sent it's request ?" Neither websockets nor SSE are truely push - they require client to make a specific request first. But yes, there is a feature of HTTP/2 called server push. The client should not ignore that data, or even worse disconnect. But again: do not implement this yourself. It is not worth it, life is too short.
